# Shiro mock subject and roles

Tags: shiro

Is there an example on how to mock a subject and roles in junit? I would like to mock the subject with a specific set of roles. This [link](http://shiro.apache.org/testing.html) doesn't explain how to accomplish this task. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The 'Unit Testing' section of the linked page shows how to create mocks.  See the `ExampleShiroUnitTest` code sample using EasyMock.

You would have to mock `subject.hasRole` calls:

```
expect(subject.hasRole(eq("aRoleName")).andReturn(true);
```

Comment: Thanks Les but I want to be able to define all of the roles that a subject may have. I have certain cases I need to check. I am validating against the subject.checkRoles method and I don't want to just do nothing / throw accessdeniedexception whenever subject.checkRoles is called